# Openfire xmpp server and Spectrum 2 IM Solaris and Linux

Tags: linux, xmpp, openfire, solaris-10

I was wondering if it is possible to run Openfire and Spectrum 2 IM on a Solaris machine .  I have not been able to compile the code for Spectrum but I wanted to know if anyone knew if running Spectrum IM on solaris 10 is feasible.  If it cannot run on Solaris, is it possible to run Openfire on a Solaris server and have Spectrum IM run on a separate linux server?

I'm also having slight problems with downloading Spectrum IM on my Linux VM. I added

```
deb http://repo.spectrum.im $dist main
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list like it says [here](http://spectrum.im/documentation/installation/debian_ubuntu.html).  and ran

```
sudo apt-get install spectrum2 spectrum2-backend-libpurple
```

and got as output

```
E: Unable to locate package spectrum2
E: Unable to loacate package spectrum2-backend-libpurple
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  $dist is supposed to be the actual dist of my linux box.  I'll juts take a lap now.